# How can we integrate Firebase Hosting with Firebase Realtime Database / Storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

Now that Firebase provides Web Hosting services, how can we integrate Firebase Hosting with Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Storage?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Hosting is static hosting for your web app.So you can use HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

JavaScript Code:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();


 // Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create
 references in your storage bucket

  var storage = firebase.storage();

</script>
```

For More See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

Comment: Firebase hosting, firebase storage, and Firebase database all reside on the Google Cloud. Why do we need to combine them at client end?

Comment: You can use any firebase service in your mobile app,web app hosted by firebase as well as other hosting.You donot need to use all firebase service and select service you want.So you donot need to import all firebase library which will reduce you app size.

Comment: How secure is this? everyone will be able to see your apiKey, authDomain, etc

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado check https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#config-files-objects